# How to combine different job reports as a chart in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

How can we combine different build reports in team city?
Consider all builds are chained and final job will show report of all jobs in chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [artifact dependencies](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Artifact+Dependencies) from the last build configuration in the build chain to all needed build configurations. So all the reports will be downloaded by the last build configuration.

1. If the reports are in HTML format you can publish it as TeamCity artifact and configure Report tab to make the reports available as an extra tabs on the build or project level.
2. Another approach is to use XML Report processing build feature that allows using report files produced by an external tool in TeamCity. TeamCity will parse the specified files on the disk and report the results as the build results.

For more details see [how to present data in TeamCity](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=54334889#HowTo...-IntegratewithBuildandReportingTools) in the documentation.